# Run Aurelia CLI app from a directory

Tags: aurelia

I would like to deploy my app to a virtual directory. I have been unable to figure out the correct configuration needed to run the app locally with a similar structure. For example, I'd like to run it from:

http://localhost:8080/demos

I have tried every combination of adding "demos" to `publicPath` and `contentBase` in my webpack config. The errors just between 404's on static assets and router errors from Aurelia.

Comment: Not enough info to help you. How are you serving those files? What do the logs look like? What's your webpack config look like?

Comment: Just add / at end of your path and try whether you are getting errors or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented by Aurelia router, you can add base tag to index.html header, `<base href="/demos">`, and set router root `config.options.root = "/demos";` in `configureRouter()`.

In addition, if your bundled js files are indeed served from directory, you need to modified `baseDir` in 2 places of `aurelia.json`: `platform.baseDir` and `build.targets[0].baseDir`.